# Iterate through session array?

Tags: php

I haven't use PHP for some time, and I need some help to create some lines of code. I wrote this line of code some years ago for a website

```
array_push($_SESSION['buildingsAlreadySeenList'],$id);
```

This is my problem, I just want to iterate through the array and put the first value at index 0 to $buildingId and then next time put the value of index 1 to $buildingId with som While loop i guess? I know it's easy, but sadly I haven't used PHP for some time! Preciate the help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use foreach()

```
foreach($_SESSION['buildingsAlreadySeenList'] as $id => $value) {
    echo $id; // this is the index and for the first time this is like to give o if the indexes were not manipulated somehow

    //put the index value to buildingid
    $buildingId = $id;
    echo $value; //the actual value of the array
}
```

---

#### Update

To check if the array is empty count the variables

```
if(count($_SESSION['buildingsAlreadySeenList'])) { 
   //array is not empty
} else {
   //array is empty
}
```

Comment: Great! Is there also a simple way to check if the array is empty?

Comment: Just a little confused, shouldn't it be $buildingId = $value !?

Comment: AHA, now I get it! echo $id shows the index number and $value the content at the index position!?

Comment: @3D-kreativ, I am not sure about that, $value give the actual content of the array whereas the $id, gets the index of the array

Comment: No not sice I added a dollar sign before the value in the first line

Comment: PAAMAYIM NEKUDOTAYIM  is an `::` symbol. And as per the code, you have posted, i dont know where such error would occur and yes `$` is needed to represent an identifier throughout the PHP excepts for `constants`

Comment: Yes, but haven't you missed $ in the first line of code? $value not just value?